# VSCode C/C++ Intellisense with Clang/MinGW

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, clang

I am trying to get Clang to work with VSCode. I've hit success on the terminal, but VSCode is still refusing to cooperate.

Clang on Windows by default targets `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`, but the reason I'm using VSCode is I'm avoiding VS in the first place. The solution to this is to pass a target flag: `--target=x86_64-w64-windows-gnu`. This allows Clang to work with MinGW headers - on the terminal at least.

VSCode detects the presence of both Clang and MinGW-w64, and changing the Intellisense mode to `windows-gcc-x64` allows it to work properly. However, changing the compiler path to Clang breaks Intellisense entirely - I've changed the Intellisense mode to `windows-clang-x64` and `windows-clang-x86`, added a hard link at `C:\MinGW` and `C:\mingw64` pointing at the MinGW installation, all to no avail. In all cases `$PATH` contains the MinGW `bin` directory, LLVM `bin` directory, and the MinGW hard link.

Any other ideas on what else I can try to get VSCode to recognize Clang?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easier why to install Clang on Windows without MSVC and it works with intellisense without problems.

go to https://www.msys2.org/ and install mysys2

then open mysys2 terminal and copy those commands to install Clang:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-clang

pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-clang-tools-extra
```

dont forget to add `msys64\mingw64\bin` to the SYSTEM PATH variable

Now Intellisense should work

I have also made a video about it if you want to check it : https://youtu.be/5OSO8IRlyXc

Comment: Does it work with clang64 environment as well?